# Send login IDs or use cookies (Android/PHP)

Tags: php, android, cookies, authentication

I'm making an Android app (client) with PHP (as server).
Basically there will be users(imagine a social app).

What is the proper method in managing logins in mobile application(Because the app could be closed, the responses delayed, the phone shut down, disconnected, etc.) ?

Should I check the login/pass in a login Android activity, store them in sharedpreferences if they are correct and then send them with every request from the user(app) ? Or should I use cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but one option is: You may return the PHPSESSID and store the value in SharedPreferences and (if user is connected to the internet) send this PHPSESSID in every Activity or request that the user needs to be logged to verify if that session is still active.